# Retrieve only one record based on name

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 columns name,id,amount. I created 5 rows with same name. Now i retrieve one row which is topped.
Here i added my code,

```
<?php
$name = "SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM calculation";
$query = mysqli_query($conn,$name);

$count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

echo "<div class='container'>
        <table class='table'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Email</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>".$row['name']."</td>
        <td>".$row['phone']."</td>
        <td>".$row['balance']."</td>
      </tr></table></div>";
               }    
                mysqli_close($conn);
                     ?>
```

Comment: use `MAX` or `LIMIT` in your query!!

Comment: "I retrieve one row which is topped" - What do you mean? How is the row you want returned determined?

Comment: You want to retrieve only one row or all rows?

Comment: Use your phpmyadmin SQL tab (if youre working with it), and try some queries. Like : SELECT min( id ) AS ID FROM test WHERE name = 'value1';

Comment: i want to avoid all rows exect one based on their amount value

Comment: Your query only selects the `name` column. What do you expect to find in `$row['phone']` and `$row['balance']` when you didn't request those columns?

Comment: we have few rows each one differentiate from amount value so i need to take row depend upon least amount value

Comment: hi i want to find month difference between mysql stored date and current date using php or jquery is there any way to find that

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT` like this:

```
$name = "SELECT name
FROM calculation GROUP BY name";
```

OR

```
$name = "SELECT name
FROM calculation LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Why use `DISTINCT` with `GROUP BY`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the LIMIT clause in your SQL query:

```
$name = "SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM calculation
LIMIT 1";
```